# TextBox: how to disable beep when pressing Ctrl+a?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I have a standard textbox.  I added the following code to enable the user to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select all text in the RTB:

```
Private Sub tb_teamList_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles tb_teamList.KeyDown
    If e.Control = True AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        tb_teamList.SelectAll()
    End If
End Sub
```

Now it still beeps when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.  Is there a way to make it *not* beep when the keys are pressed?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11820552/49251

Comment: Why do you need to add code? I just tried selecting text in a RTB in WinForms, and I can use Ctrl+a without adding any custom code.

Comment: No need to any specific code to do this task in RichTextbox.

Comment: Ahh I see... I used a normal multi-line textbox. Silly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then to disable the beep sound when pressing Ctl+A in the multi-line TextBox you will add `e.SuppressKeyPress = True` to your code :

```
Private Sub tb_teamList_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles tb_teamList.KeyDown
    If e.Control = True AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        tb_teamList.SelectAll()
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```